# Why can't I directly substitute $x={0^+}$ in this limit question?

Tags: limits

So the question is to find the limit of:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{-1+\sqrt{(\tan x-\sin x) +\sqrt{(\tan x-\sin x) +\sqrt{(\tan x-\sin x})\ldots\infty } }}{-1+\sqrt{x^3+\sqrt{x^3}+ \sqrt{x^3}...\infty}}.$$

I directly substituted $x= 0$, since it doesn't form any indeterminate form, which gives the answer as $$\frac{-1}{-1} = 1.$$

However the correct answer to the question $\frac 12$.

Comment: Maybe you read the question wrong?

Comment: @Tavish you meant the answer ?

Comment: It seems like the nested radicals converge to 0 in your “wrong answer”

Comment: No, but either the question or the answer could be wrong.

Comment: Expressions with $...\infty$ in them are not rigorous mathematical expressions and are not generally subject to the laws of algebra and calculus. I don't even know what it means to "directly substitute $x=0$" into such an expression.

Comment: The function isn't continuous at 0 so you can't do that. Try evaluating the nested expressions first.

Comment: What Lee Mosher is saying is of course nonsense. Lots of rigorous mathematical expressions contain the symbol $\infty$ in them. Don't let that kind of misinformation spread to you. The actual reason that that said by cybershiptrooper. That recipe of a limit being the evaluation of the function at the point, is the definition of "continuous at a point". It is applied when you know before hand, potentially by a different argument, that the function in question is continuous.

Comment: @plop He said the expression "$\cdots\infty$" not $\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there are *three* limit operations in the expression. The "$\cdots$" in the numerator must be interpreted as a limit of iterating
$$y\mapsto \sqrt{ (\tan x - \sin x) + y} $$
and similarly the "$\cdots$" in the denominator must be the limit of iterating
$$ y \mapsto \sqrt{x^3 + y} $$
Only when *those* limits have been found for a fixed positive $x$ can we begin to let the *explicit* $x\to 0^+$ limit take place.

The two iterations both have the shape $y\mapsto \sqrt{A+y}$, where $A$ is a positive constant that depends on $x$. The limit of the iteration must be a fixed point, so we have
$$ y = \sqrt{A+y} \implies y^2 = A + y \implies y = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4A}}{2} $$
but only the positive solution here is really a fixed point -- the other one corresponds to $y=-\sqrt{A+y}$.

So what we're really after is
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{-1 + \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4(\tan x-\sin x))}}{2}}
{-1 + \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x^3}}{2}} $$

which is an indeterminate form $\lim\frac{\to 0}{\to 0}$.

---

Even if we try to plug in $x=0$ immediately, we're left trying to evaluate
$$ \sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\cdots}}} $$
It may look like there's never any reason for this to become nonzero, so the value "should be" zero. However, note that the suggestive "$\cdots$" notation doesn't tell us where to *start* the $y\mapsto \sqrt{0+y}$ iteration. When $A>0$ it so happens that we reach the same fixed point no matter what our initial $y$ is. For $A=0$, we can *either* start it at $y=0$, which then stays there forever, *or* at any positive number, and *then* the limit of successively taking the square root is $1$ rather than $0$. And it's the limit of $1$ that's actually continuous with the answer in the $A>0$ case.